# CSRF атаки - защита

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Необходимо обезопаситься от CSRF атак. Какие готовые библиотеки существуют? Или кто-нибудь писал для себя? Или же помогите с принципом работы.

Как я понял, нужно каждый раз вставлять hidden input с с сессией и и проверять ее? Но как лучше всего это сделать, чтобы не редактировать сотни форм, а всего лишь подредактировать код. За ранее спасибо

Comment: Зачем кучу вопросов и впадать из крайности в крайность?
Определись с одной стихией и покоряй следующую

А это пахнет повтором [вопрос ][1]

И еще настолько ли проект нужно обезопасить? В большинстве случаев такие вопросы сводятся к ответу, один раз используют и забывают о нем. сколько тут было вопросов про безопасность и прочее, потом кто-то все-таки выложил сайт на просмотр, не все оценили прежде всего свой труд, в качестве ответом. сайт ужасен был, вопрос не помню жаль.

Так что если писать сайты для себя и для практики, то не стоит так париться


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/77943/

Comment: Сайт крайне не повтор. Темы разные. Я лишь прошу подсказать несколько классов, библиотек по этой защитите или же принцип работы. Сайт требует полнейшей безопасности.

Comment: Вы наверное уже искали информацию по этой теме, скажем в Google : **CSRF атаки  защита** , [например это](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1175)

чем не годится ?

Comment: Ты прав. Но все же нужно своими силами обезопасить сайт.

Comment: @avp, я уже пробовал этот метод, с этого же сайта. Не получилось или же не совсем ясно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если честно, не вчитывался, что они *(Google : **CSRF атаки защита**)* предлагают. Суть в следующем.

У пользователя с формой в браузере работает, скажем JS. При передаче формы сервер генерит некий *токен* (строку символов) и знает, что клиент (реально JS, связанный с формой) в браузере должен заменить этот *токен* не другой (по некоторому алгоритму, известному клиенту и серверу) при отправке формы на сервер. Получив форму сервер сравнивает полученный *токен* с ожидаемым.

Алгоритм изменения токена может быть основан, например, на знании пароля (или его хэша) как сервером, так и клиентом.

Вот, собственно, и вся идея.

Comment: Сессии - вариант?

Comment: Токен в переменных сессии ? Да сколько угодно.

Answer (score 1):

> Распространённым способом защиты
> является механизм, когда с каждой
> сессией пользователя ассоциируется
> дополнительный секретный ключ,
> предназначенный для выполнения
> POST-запросов. Пользователь посылает
> этот ключ внутри тела каждого
> POST-запроса, при выполнении
> каких-либо действий, а сервер
> проверяет этот ключ. Преимуществом
> данного механизма является отсутствие
> необходимости осуществлять парсинг
> поля HTTP_REFERER, а значит и нет
> необходимости учитывать множество
> нюансов возможных вариантов
> присутствия или отсутствия различных
> элементов этого поля. Недостатком же
> являются: требование возможности
> организации пользовательских сессий и
> требование динамической генерации
> HTML-кода активных страниц сайта.

ИМХО всего не предусмотришь, для борьбы с атаками нужны силы не одного человека! тут упор стоит на сисадминов и отдела программистов. Один в поле не воин!

Больше чем написано в нете ты не узнаешь. так что просто проверяй те поля которые считаешь нужными. Лишнее отбрасывай. и никогда не доверяй данным введенным от пользователя. Больше мне добавить нечего.

Comment: Жаль, что HTTP_REFERER не кроссбраузерный.

Comment: да ты суть пойми а не к словам цепляйся.

Хочешь сделать защиту, проверяй все! иначе вся эта затея буэ.

Answer (score 0):

Для Zend Framework есть [хороший и проверенный метод](http://plutov.by/post/zf_csrf)